# how to read and store rgb values of each pixel after image quantization

Tags: matlab

Hi
i have quantized an image to 64 colors using 
[img1,map]=rgb2ind(RGB_img,64);
now i want to read the rbg values of each pixel of the quantized image 'img1' and store it in a variable.
please help
with regards 
dev

Answer (score 1):

Not positive if this will work, but this is what is from the matlab documentation

A colormap is an m-by-3 matrix of real numbers between 0.0 and 1.0. Each row is an RGB vector that defines one color. The kth row of the colormap defines the kth color, where map(k,:) = [r(k) g(k) b(k)]) specifies the intensity of red, green, and blue.

so
map(k,1)*255 would get you the R value in the range of 0-255 for the kth color.  You would need to implement some logic to determine the index of each pixel and map it into the corresponding value.

sorry I don't have matlab on the box I am on right now or I would give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the red, green, and blue components of the quantized image by indexing each corresponding column of the 64-by-3 color map with the indexed image values:

```
RGB_img = imread(imageFile);                 %# Load an RGB image
[img1,map] = rgb2ind(RGB_img,64);            %# Create your quantized image
rPlane = reshape(map(img1+1,1),size(img1));  %# Red color plane for image
gPlane = reshape(map(img1+1,2),size(img1));  %# Green color plane for image
bPlane = reshape(map(img1+1,3),size(img1));  %# Blue color plane for image
```

Notice you have to add 1 to `img1` when using it as an index since the index values run from 0 to 63.

For example, here are some results using `'peppers.png'` for `imageFile`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here's something I did for my own amusement a while back.
Skip the main function.
Look for the "ofstream out" object in the functions. Hope u will get some idea.
This code is full of bugs I think.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void Encrypt();
void Decrypt();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while(true){
        system("cls");
        cout << "1. Encrypt" << endl;
        cout << "2. Decrypt" << endl;
        cout << "3. Exit" << endl;

        int choice;
        cout << endl << "Enter choice : " ;

        cin >> choice;

        if(choice == 1)
            Encrypt();
        else if(choice == 2)
            Decrypt();
        else
            exit(0);
    }

        return 0;
}

void Encrypt()
{

    ifstream in_image;
    ifstream in_file;
    ofstream out;

    system("cls");

    char* im_in = new char[200];
    char* f_in = new char[200];
    char* im_out = new char[200];

    cout << "Enter input image file(.tga) : " ;
    cin >> im_in;
    cout << "Enter input file : " ;
    cin >> f_in;
    cout << "Enter output file : " ;
    cin >> im_out;

    in_image.open(im_in, ios::in|ios::binary);
    in_file.open(f_in, ios::in|ios::binary);
    out.open(im_out, ios::out|ios::binary);

//    struct stat results;
//    if(stat(f_in, &results) != 0)
//    {    
//        cout << "Error opening input file!" << endl;
//        exit(1);
//    }

    delete im_in;
    delete im_out;
    delete f_in;

    int i, j, k;

    char* image_header = new char[54];
    char* image_buffer = new char[16];
    char* file_in_buffer = new char[1];
    char temp;

    int *bits = new int[8];                //Array to keep the bits in a byte.

    int operand; 

    in_image.read(image_header, 54);

    int f_length = 0;

    image_header[5] = (char)f_length%256;    
    image_header[6] = (char)(f_length/256)%256;
    image_header[7] = (char)(f_length/256)/256;

    out.write(image_header, 54);

    i = 0;

    do
    {
        in_image.read(image_buffer, 16);
        in_file.read(file_in_buffer, 1);

        if(in_file)
        {
            operand = 1;

            for(j = 0; j <8; j++)
            {
                if((file_in_buffer[0] & operand) != 0)    //Copying the file_in_buffer to the array.
                    bits[j] = 1;
                else
                    bits[j] = 0;
                operand = operand << 1;
            }

            k=0;

            for(j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            {
                if(j%4 == 0 || j%4 == 1)
                {
                    image_buffer[j] = image_buffer[j] & (-2);        //Making the last bit 0.
                    image_buffer[j] = image_buffer[j] ^ bits[k];
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }

        out.write(image_buffer, 16);
        i++;

    }while(in_image);

    in_image.close();
    in_file.close();
    out.close();

    delete image_header;
    delete image_buffer;
    delete file_in_buffer;
    delete bits;
}    

void Decrypt()
{
    system("cls");

    ifstream image;
    ofstream out;

    char* im_in = new char[200];
    char* f_out = new char[200];

    cout << "Enter input image file(.tga) : " ;
    cin >> im_in;
    cout << "Enter output file : " ;
    cin >> f_out;

    image.open(im_in, ios::in | ios::binary);
    out.open(f_out, ios::out|ios::binary);

    delete im_in;
    delete f_out;

    char image_header[54];
    char image_buffer[16];
    char* temp = new char[1];
    int tempi;

    int bits[8];
    int i, j, k;

    int operand;

    image.read(image_header, 54);
    int f_length = 0;

    for(i = 0; i <1; i ++)
    {
        if(image_header[i+5] > -1)
            f_length += image_header[i+5]*pow(256, i); 
        else
            f_length += (256 + image_header[i+5])*pow(256, i);
    }


    i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < f_length; i++)
    {

        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            bits[j] = 0;
        }

        image.read(image_buffer, 16);


        k = 0;

        for(j = 0; j <16; j++)
        {
            if(j%4 == 0 || j%4 == 1)
            {
                bits[k] = image_buffer[j] & 1;
                k++;
            }

        }

        tempi = 0;
        operand = 1;

        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            tempi += (bits[j]<<j) & operand;
            operand = operand << 1;
        }

        temp[0] = (char)tempi;

        out.write(temp, 1);


    }while(image);

    image.close();
    out.close();

    delete image_header;
    delete image_buffer;
//    delete temp;
}
```